# Cannot return a fixed size array because of a syntax error: expected one of 7 possible tokens

Tags: arrays, rust

I am trying to return a fixed-sized array on the stack from a function without using dynamic allocation (such as using `Vec<i32>`), but I cannot do that because of the compile error that complains about syntax.

### Code

```
const ARRAY_SIZE: i32 = 4;

fn main() {
    println!("this is {:?}", test());
}

fn test() -> [i32: ARRAY_SIZE] {
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2047e6cb18016e43457e8d13266201e)

### Compiler output

```
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `+`, `::`, `;`, `<`, or `]`, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 | fn test() -> [i32: ARRAY_SIZE] {
  |                  ^ expected one of 7 possible tokens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of fixed size is defined with `;`, not `:`, and its size is of type `usize`, not `i32`. You want the following:

```rust
const ARRAY_SIZE : usize = 4; 
...
fn test() -> [i32; ARRAY_SIZE] {
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```